# Scrape google finance peer ticker

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape the tickers of peer companies form Google Finance. For Example:

https://www.google.com/search?q=appl&tbm=fin#scso=_tUXMXLuxNKqAk74Pr7CV6AU2:0.3999938964844.0666809082031.4666748046875.800048828125.3333740234375.2000122070312.066650390625.1333618164062.200000047683716.266666889190674.2666625976562.066650390625.8666381835938.666666984558105,_JUbMXNapK6iXmwWQnaSACg3:0,_mEbMXIMFifXpBJLNp3g2:0&wptab=COMPARE

Amazon - Ticker: Amzn

I am trying it with bs4 but it just doesnt work. In my understanding it should

peer = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'wfbQZb'})[1].text

but I only get [] an empty list.

Expected result should be for example AMZN

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


# google finance
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=appl&tbm=fin&wptab=COMPARE#scso=_8kbMXPcSiYaTvg_4maugCg2:0&wptab=COMPARE"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Andi\Desktop\test2\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

html_source = driver.page_source
print(html_source)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
peer = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'wfbQZb'})[0].text
print(peer)

driver.quit()
```